# Getting a line number of a string in a textfield in Actionscript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a textfield and i want to search the text within for its line number and then scroll to that line number.  This is quite easy in AS3 but i have to accomplish it in AS2.  I cannot seem to find any way to do this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Greensock's TextMetrics for AS2 might be of use here: http://www.greensock.com/textmetrics/.

> Have you ever needed to find out where the line breaks occur in a dynamic TextField? How about the precise x/y coordinates of a particular phrase/string along with its width & height so that you could highlight it somehow? Or maybe the width of each line of text? That’s all possible with the gs.utils.text.TextMetrics class.

Sounds like the info on line breaks would be useful, or you could possibly use text x and y along with line height and font size to determine line number.

Comment: Hmm, sadly this is for use within scaleform so i am not sure that will work but worth a shot.  Thanks for the tip.